# Simple Webmatrix AJAX post form

Tags: ajax, jquery, razor, webmatrix

I'm trying to create a really simple post form, which will add an email address to my database, and then change the submit button to "Thank You". I'm having some issues, and I don't know whether the issue lies with my AJAX code, or with the partials page, which adds it to the database.

Here's my code:

Form:

```
<div id="myform">
<form action=""name="subscribe-form">
<h5>Subscribe to our “New Property” newsletter.</h5>
<div class="controls">
    <input name="subscribe-email" id="subscribe-email" type="email" class="span4" placeholder="Email">
</div>

<p style="color: #fff">You can unsubscribe at any time if you don’t find it useful and informative.</p>
<div class="controls">
    <button id="subscribe-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function(){
 $('#subscribe-submit').click(function(){ 
 var dataString = 'email='+ subscribe=email;            
    $.ajax({        
            type: "POST",
            url: "~/Partials/NewsletterSubscription.cshtml",
            data: dataString,                          
            success: function (data) {
            $('#myform').html(data);
            <button id="subscribe-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Thankyou</button>
        } 
        return false;       
        });
      });                 
   });
</script>
```

Partial:

```
@{
layout = null;
if(IsPost){
var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");
var sql = "INSERT INTO NewsletterSubscription (Email, CreatedDate) VALUES (@0, GetDate())";
var email = Request["subscribe-email"];
db.Execute(sql, email);
}
}
```

Comment: What issues do you have?

Comment: What errors or unexpected results are you getting here?

Comment: This can be closed as lacking a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the line `<button id="subscribe-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn primary">Thankyou</button>` should do, but if you want to change the text of the button, you do this like so: `$("#subscribe-submit").html("Thank you");`